# Changing what component returns after it completes a long operation

Tags: reactjs, async-await, promise

My component looks like this:

```
export default function MyComponent(){        
    //long async operation
    //return something that is set inside the async operation
}
```

As the async operation takes some time, the `return` statement runs before the async task is over, therefore it returns something incomplete.

How can I change what the component returns after a randomly long async operation (or promise) give me some results after ending?

Comment: There's a larger, more idiomatic (and more user friendly) solution. When you have to fetch data, you have to maintain some state -- i.e. whether the data is loading or has finished fetching. Based on that state, you show a loading UI, then update state/rerender when ready to show the contentful UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use state to determine when data is loading/complete/failed

```
export default function MyComponent(){
   const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
   const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
   const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
   React.useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(true);
      longAsyncOperation()
        .then((data) => {
            setData(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            setError(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        });
   }, []);        
 
   return isLoading 
      ? (<div>Loading</div>) 
      : error || !data ? (<div>{error.message}</div>)
      : (<div>Complete!</div>)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a state and update it once the async operation is over:

```js
export default function MyComponent(){
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState();        
  setLoading(true);
    //long async operation
  setLoading(false);//this should run once the async operation has finished
    //return something that is set inside the async operation
  return loading ? <LoadingComponent /> : <MyView />;
}
```